# linux kernel programming infinite loop

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Completely new to linux kernel programming, wondering why my device read and write is throwing an infinite loop when I do:

```
echo "hi" > simpchar
cat simpchar
```

```
static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp, char *buff,
        size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
    int bytes_read = 0;
    int idxr = 0;
    while (len && (msg[idxr] != 0)) {
        put_user(msg[idxr], buff++);
        len--;
        bytes_read++;
        idxr++;
    }   
    return bytes_read;
}

static ssize_t device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff,
        size_t len, loff_t * off)
{
    int bytes_read = 0;
    memset(msg, 0, BUF_LEN);
    int idxr = 0;
    while (len > 0) {
        msg[idxr++] = buff[idxr++];  
        len--;
        bytes_read++;
    }   
    return bytes_read;
}
```

Comment: Is `simpchar`? the char dev to reading or writing on to? then the command has to be `echo "hi" > simpchar && cat simpchar`

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing here is the update to `loff_t * off`.
This is the way for the file descriptor to keep up with your location in the file.

In your code, each call to read()/write() always starts at offset 0.

See [how-to-test-your-own-linux-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077140/how-to-test-your-own-linux-module)

Answer (score 1):

One small mistake though. You have given idxr++ in both as message[idxr++]=buffer[idxr++]. This will increment idxr twice, so you won't get your result even if it doesn't run into an infinite loop. Create a new variable say count=0 and try and return count.

Comment: `len` has always counted down to zero.  `bytes_read` is the value that `len` had initially, and is the correct return value (although it should be called `bytes_written`, of course).